# Need to perform actions on EF objects with common fields, not sure if/how I need to use Interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I'm using Entity Framework. I have a few database tables that store different statistics:

Stats1 (Stats1ID, Mean)
Stats2 (Stats2ID, Mean)
Stats3 (Stats3ID, Mean)

I have multiple methods which I want to consolidate into a single method. The only difference between these methods are the parameters:

```
public static bool IsValid(Stats1 stat, decimal value) { // }
public static bool IsValid(Stats2 stat, decimal value) { // }
// etc
```

The methods all use the common field of these different Stat objects - 'Mean'. How do I replace the first parameter with some generic object that I can use to access the Mean field of whichever type is passed in? Not sure if this is relevant but I use "database first" and generate the model like that

**edit:** appreciate the answers, will test things soon

Comment: Are you using any other properties from these entities in these methods? I mean can't you just pass the Mean property instead of StatsX? Or do they differ?

Comment: I could but it's more a theoretical question because there's more to it than what I've posted, and I want to apply it elsewhere. But yeah you're correct. I'll go that way if I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Stats` classes can implement an interface, say `IStat`, containing the `Mean` property. It's enough to extend a generated partial class by another partial class:

```
partial class Stats1 : IStat { }
```

EF doesn't mind, as long as you don't use the interface for navigation property types (but you won't with database first).

Then you can define a generic method with a generic type constraint (`where`):

```
public static bool IsValid<T>(T stat, decimal value)
    where T : IStat
{
    // Example of what you could do here: 
    return stat.Mean > value);
}
```

Usage:

```
var valid = IsValid(stat1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Didn't notice you're using Database First. I use this approach in code first, and it probably don't apply to you. But I leave it here in case anyone reads the question later.

---

You can define an `interface` that denoted the common field, like:

```
public interface IStatEntity
{
    public int Mean { get; set; }
}
```

and implement the interface on all of the entities. Implementing an interface does not interfere with EF's mappings and doesn't mean anything to EF.

I use the same approach for having properties such as `CreationTime` and `LastModificationTime` and then setting them centrally in my `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to do what you want.

```
public static bool IsValid<TStats>(TStats stats, decimal value)
{
    if (Equals(stats, null))
        return false;

    // Get the 'Mean' property
    var propertyInfo = typeof(TStats).GetProperty("Mean");

    if (Equals(propertyInfo, null))
        return false;

    // Get
    var meanValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(stats, null) as decimal?;

    // ... do what ever you want with the meanValue
    return meanValue.HasValue && meanValue.Value == value;
}
```